# Converting Maven project to EAR

Tags: java, maven, ear

I am new to maven. 
I have created a maven project , in this i have two`session beans`  and i have added all dependencies in `pom.xml`. I want to conver this project to `EAR`so that I can deploy it on `jboss EAP 6.0` .

I have used 
      `<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>`

but it doen't provide the runtime dependencies.

How do i convert maven project to EAR file. How do get all dependencies including project dependencies at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using maven-ear-plugin. The pom.xml would have the following item inside `<build><plugins>..</plugins>..</build>` listing:
(taken from the documentation)

```
  <build>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8</version>
      <configuration>
      <!-- configuration elements go here -->
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
```

Please also refer to the documentation here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html.

Maven handles all the dependencies that you list in the `<dependencies>...</dependencies>` section that follows the above block. For example:

```
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

You can get the dependency details, like the above for log4j, from various maven repositories online. (http://search.maven.org/, http://mvnrepository.com/ etc.)